# C# List all Folders on a SQL reporting server using ReportingServices

Tags: c#

I'm just trying to get a list of all the folders that resides on a sql server running reporting services.  I'm using the web service ReportingServices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var rs = new ReportingService2005SoapClient();

    CatalogItem[] reports;

    string reportPath = "/ReportPath";

    rs.ListChildren(reportPath, true, out reports);

    foreach (var report in reports)
    {
        if (report.Type == ItemTypeEnum.Folder)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mike, "/ReportPath" was only meant as an example.  Use the path that your reports are contained in or simply use "/" for the root path.

Comment: hey can you give a look over here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759492/c-ssrs-wont-publish-report-but-it-returns-successful-as-if-it-did